# special characters in html instead od utf 8 encoding

Tags: html

I have designed a html page where code look like following

```
<!DOCTYPE   html    PUBLIC  "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta   http-equiv="Content-Type"   content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"  />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body   style="margin:0;">
<div    id="alignment"  align="center">
<table  id="border" bgcolor="#e5e5e5"   border="0"  cellpadding="20"    cellspacing="0"         width="726">
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size:  19px;   color:  #FFF;background:#080808;" align="left">hi–boss</td>
</tr>   
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but in output I get   hi�boss  instead of hi- boss.

Can any one say , what I miss here.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try change the default_charset to UTF-8 in the php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

Your document is in fact not UTF-8 encoded but probably windows-1252. You will see this if you manually use the View menu of your browser and there set the encoding to windows-1252 (it may appear under the name “West European” (Windows) for example).

Therefore, either save it as UTF-8 encoded in your authoring software or change “UTF-8” to “windows-1252”.

Further complications are possible if the server sends an HTTP header that declares character encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you copied the `-` from a non-utf8 charset. You have to specify this in you meta-tags, use '-' (the one on your keyboard), or if you use php e.g. call `utf8_encode("text")`.

Comment: No I have typed it from keyboard.

Comment: Then you have a strange keyboard. The character in your sample is 0x96, which is the CP-1252 "en-dash" character and is not valid in UTF-8. The Unicode version is `&#x2013;` or `&#8211;`.